# How to install ChromeDriver or Gekodriver in Ubuntu MATE for the Raspberry Pi 2 and Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: java, selenium, raspberry-pi

I was working on project to run java- selenium project in Rasbery pi hooked up to TV. It is really hard to find the correct chromium driver or geko driver matching with raspberry pi architecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem using below steps

Install Firefox Web browser

```
sudo apt-get install firefox
```

Install the arm7hf based geko driver to rasbery pi.  https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

You can use the below commands to install the geko driver

```
cd /usr/local/

wget https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.15.0/geckodriver-v0.15.0-arm7hf.tar.gz

tar -xvzf geckodriver*

chmod +x geckodriver

export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/geckodriver
```

Now you are all set to run selenium scripts in Raspberry pi :)
Make sure you have the below code piece in you selenium scripts

```
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/usr/local/geckodriver");
          webDriver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Comment: To work with newer firefox browsers get the gecko driver form below git hub location

https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/tag/v0.23.0